# Android SQLite Error "no such column", but column exists

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I get an error when I try to update a database row in my Android app. It seems to think there's no column called `last_update_time`, but I'm absolutely sure there is one. I've created and re-created the database a few times and checked my SQL statements, and there is definitely a column by this name.

Some log statements:

```
02-13 14:31:09.508: I/Database(674): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = no such column: last_update_time

02-13 14:31:09.508: E/Database(674): Error updating icon=http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/restaurant-71.png last_update_time=1329172268604 distance=36.571194 _id=ba1f46d735746b66658bb970e842d647ea7f92d8 vicinity=3561 El Camino Real #75,
 Santa Clara name=Paris Baguette longitude=-121.994223 latitude=37.353605 types=bakery store food establishment reference=
 CnRlAAAAddN_wZD9BvHL0LCzxJUgzf_QcaFUVcIyDRPf26pRyrUVJ1yVkUkke420FEhwkaNfsZedlqrhaRJJwelopAYWEPRr7mAL81vivvlntYSSqS0xUxke655C7ay4AyOpaCO1BE7XbDmQSTV7WINl8c7W0hIQ_DXJBG0pSWe3P1gaJQOSuRoURMAs2eYOIzExARulJ7B7k5EK97c using UPDATE places SET icon=?,
 last_update_time=?, distance=?, _id=?, vicinity=?, name=?, longitude=?, latitude=?, types=?, reference=? WHERE _id = ba1f46d735746b66658bb970e842d647ea7f92d8

02-13 14:31:09.518: E/AndroidRuntime(674): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: last_update_time: , while compiling: UPDATE places SET icon=?,
 last_update_time=?, distance=?, _id=?, vicinity=?, name=?, longitude=?, latitude=?, types=?, reference=? WHERE _id = ba1f46d735746b66658bb970e842d647ea7f92d8
```

Comment: Try dropping the table and recreating or unistalling the app and reinstalling. If you are not doing a proper upgrade, then the column won't exist.

Comment: Show the code where you are creating the table

Comment: Nevermind, problem solved. I was missing a comma in my create table statement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just a shot in the dark here... but it looks like you are missing a comma in your create table statement.